# Key Press Event not stopping backspace

Tags: jquery, events, textbox, restrict

I have a textbox where I need to prevent the user from manually entering anything into it. I wrote a `keypress` event handler in the following manner:

```
funcion Keypress(Event e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

By using the above code, I was able to restrict the user to not enter any thing. The value in the textbox will be filled by some other event (a dropdown change).

After the value is filled in the textbox, if I use backspace , it still is working and deleting the data in the text box.

Can any one please suggest me to restrict any keypress on the textbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `readonly` attribute to do this, no JS required.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" readonly="true" />
```

This still allows you to set the value programmatically via javascript.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/GHH7a/)

Comment: Excellent answer. Can you provide any detail on why his original code does not work? This may provide insight for those with the same problem, but who may not necessarily need to prevent _ALL_ input.

Comment: @DavidHoude If you wanted to do this in JS, you would need to hook the `keydown` event and use `preventDefault`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/GHH7a/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Actually i did nt forget..i tried to accept immediately..but asked me to wait for some more time. Anyways, accepted..now.:)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..can you please help me on this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860422/how-to-unload-jquery-ui-tabs-that-are-hidden-not-active..i have been trying this since two hours..