# How to unload jquery ui tabs that are hidden/ not active?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, removechild

I am using Jquery UI tabs in my asp.net mvc web application.

I have total of 6 tabs. Each tab contains a user control.

I am dynamically loading the contents into each tab using ajax like this:

```
 <div id="tabs" style="clear: both" align="center">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("AddControl","App",new {id=Model.ID}) %>">
                <span>Tab </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("Control","App",new {id=1,data=Model.ID}) %>">
                <span>Tab1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("Control","App",new {id=2,data=Model.ID}) %>">
                <span>Tab2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("Control","App",new {id=3,data=Model.ID}) %>">
                <span>Tab3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("Control","App",new {id=4,data=Model.ID}) %>">
                <span>Tab4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%:Url.Action("Control","App",new {id=5,data=Model.ID})%>">
                <span>Tab5</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1">
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" >
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" >
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" >
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" >
        </div>
        <div id="tab6">
        </div>
    </div>
```

As one can see, the tab 2 to tab 6 contains the same user control. The data will be loaded based on tab clicked.

here, my problem is once the tab is loaded , clicked on another tab , the other tab contents are just hidden.

Since, i am using the same user controls , i am facing some problems.

So, i want to remove the content  from the tabs which are hidden ( not active )

Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `activate` event in the plugin to clear the contents of the previous tab. Try this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ 
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        ui.oldPanel.empty(); // clear the content of the previous tab
    }
    // other settings, if needed...
});
```

Comment: @Rory..Thanks for your response. Including in the plugin means, including in the jquery-ui.custom.js?

Comment: @Rory..but i am getting one problem..i am using jqgrid inside tabs. After inlcuding above code, except that grid entire page is blocked.i was not able to click on page. Any ideas?